# Python - Groupby & apply row sum function

Tags: python, apply

I got a dataframe df

```
 ID A
 1  2
 1  3
 1  4
 2  1
 2  2
```

I want to iteratate over each ID group and divide the row value by its group sum, so in the end I get following output column B

```
 ID A  B
 1  2  2/9
 1  3  3/9
 1  4  4/9
 2  1  1/3
 2  2  2/3
```

I tried to write an own function with an apply command but I always get an error

```
def row_sum(input):
    sum=input/input.sum()
    return sum

df.groupby("ID").apply(row_sum: input=df["A"])
```

Any idea? Can I write this into a class & method?

Comment: what is the specific error you're getting?

Comment: also, the syntax is wrong in the last line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you apply a group by, you get an object of type `pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy`. The apply method of this class recieves a function that recieves *a dataframe* as its input.

You can try the following:

```py
def ratio_by_group(df):
    return df['A']/df['A'].sum()

df.groupby("ID").apply(ratio_by_group)
```

I'd also recommend to read the pandas documentation page on `pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html

Comment: OP wants to add column 'B': `df['B'] = df.groupby("ID",group_keys=False).apply(ratio_by_group)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try grouping by `ID` and transforming the grouped `sum` and dividing every row by it.  The whole result can be `assign`ed to a new column called `B`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], "A": [2, 3, 4, 1, 2]})
df.assign(B=df["A"] / df.groupby("ID")["A"].transform("sum"))
```

which gives

```
   ID  A         B
0   1  2  0.222222
1   1  3  0.333333
2   1  4  0.444444
3   2  1  0.333333
4   2  2  0.666667
```